# Responsive Menu not Displaying in Smartphone Default Browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

My Responsive website when i open in  **smartphone Default browser** responsive Menu is not displaying , But when i check with  **Smartphone Chrome Browser** its working fine . Can any help me out of this issue please ?

**Here is my Code :**

**Responsive CSS code here :**

```
.navigation {
    display: none;
}

.mobi-menu {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    bottom: -6px;
    outline: none;
}

.mobi-menu span {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    left: 10px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.mobi-menu span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 13px;
}

.mobi-menu span:nth-child(2) {
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -1px;
}

.mobi-menu span:nth-child(3) {
    bottom: 13px;
}

.mobi-nav-container {
    display: block;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    padding: 20px 30px 50px 50px;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 140px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}

.mobi-menu.open ~ .mobi-nav-container {
    top: 100px;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.mobi-menu.open span:first-child {
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 19px;
}

.mobi-menu.open span:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
}

.mobi-menu.open span:last-child {
    -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    bottom: 19px;
}

.mobi-navigation {
}

.mobi-navigation > li {
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.mobi-navigation > li i {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 12px;
    font-size: 80%;
}

.mobi-navigation ul {
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
}

.mobi-navigation a {
    outline: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 12px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 120%;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: dashed;
    background-color: #993399;
    z-index: 1;
}

.mobi-navigation > li > a {
}
```

**Here is my HTML Code :**

```
<div class="mobi-nav-container" style="min-height: 1209px;">
   <ul id="menu-main-1" class="mobi-navigation">
   <li id="menu-item-8" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-8">
      <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
   </li>
   <li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-20">
      <a href="">WHO WE ARE ? <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
         <li id="menu-item-185" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-185"><a href="genesis.html">THE GENESIS </a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li id="menu-item-209" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-209">
      <a href="">WHAT WE OFFER ? <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
   </li>
   <li id="menu-item-418" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-418">
      <a href="">WHAT WE DO ? <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
         <li id="menu-item-210" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-210"><a href="">CORPORATE IDENTITY  </a></li>
         </li>
         <li id="menu-item-419" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-418">
            <a href="">HOW WE DO ? <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
               <li id="menu-item-289" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-289"><a href="">THE APPROACH  </a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li id="menu-item-475" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-475"><a href="contact.html">WHERE TO LOCATE US?  </a></li>
      </ul>
      <!--end mobile navigation-->
      <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**Thanks In Advance.**

Comment: Im still shocked there's a mobile version for IE...

Comment: Sorry , its Smartphone Default Browser ..

Comment: I think you need to specify a bit more. Do you mean the default browser on Android? And, if so, which version of Android? There are loads of different versions, so in order to efficiently find the problem, please be exact about browser/OS versions.

Comment: yes i am talking about the Default browser of Android. And my Android Version is 4.1.2 .

Comment: Talking about "the Default browser of Android" doesn't mean a lot. http://slides.com/html5test/the-android-browser#/